# is it possible to set default home-directory based on the users gidnumber?

Tags: freeipa, rhel8

I'm aware that I can change the general settings by running:
ipa config-mod --homedirectory=/some/path

what I would like to achieve is for IPA to change it to a different path based on the GID/GIDnumber of the user created, e.g:

ipa user-add user10 --gidnumber=10
would create a user with home-directory /home10/user10

ipa user-add user20 --gidnumber=20
would create a user with home-directory /home20/user10

is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know it requires some repetition but can't you just use `--homedir` option of the `ipa user-add` command?